# Where to find "Families of curves on a surface of general type" (MR0457450)?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-surfaces, advice

I am currently doing some research on surfaces of general type and I need some results from Bogomolov's paper:

**Bogomolov, F. A.**
*Families of curves on a surface of general type.*
Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR 236 (1977), no. 5, 1041–1044. 
14J25 (14J05). **([MR0457450](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0457450))**.

I've been looking all over the internet but there is no PDF or online form of this paper. I went to all my local libraries and all I found was a version in Russian that was so old (and so poorly maintained) that some parts where not even readable (I don't speak russian anyway).

Is there a place where I can find this paper? I'll be happy to pay for it if necessary!

Comment: The MR item you refer to gives  a reference to the English translation: Soviet Math. Dokl. 236 (1977), no. 5, 1294–1297 (1978).  It should be in many libraries and you should be able to get a copy in PDF.  You can also ask Bogomolov directly.

Comment: I know there's an English version, but I was not able to find it in my area, I went to 8 different universities/libraries and none had the English version. One had the Russian version but it was in such terrible state it was not even readable.

Comment: I do not know what country you live in, but in the US, there is the option of "inter-library loan".  A request is sent from your library to the library which has the journal, they copy the paper in PDF and send it to your library by email.

Comment: I currently live in Colombia, so that's not an option for me. I wasn't able to find the PDF online, not even the Russian version. I might try to contact Bogomolov directly.

Comment: Your local library may contact any library that has a print copy of the Journal and they would scan it and send it by e-mail. For example, the Instituto de Matemáticas has this journal according to the page: http://biblioteca.matem.unam.mx/revistas/catalogo-de-revistas/catalogo-de-revistas-s/6868-soviet-mathematics-doklady (it is in volume 18).

Comment: I have already done that, not with the Instituto de Matemáticas in Mexico, but with some other universities my local library has contact with. It's been more than a month since I made that request but they haven't answered. At this point I have more hope in sending an email to Bogomolov

Comment: Incidentally, you might find this [Bourbaki seminar](http://www.numdam.org/article/SB_1977-1978__20__233_0.pdf) on the subject useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My local library has the paper version, here is a [scan.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/tnqqaf8royx7i6k/bogomolov.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: The Russian version is available here (in case, the DropBox link in the other answer goes down): http://mi.mathnet.ru/eng/dan41270